# How to update a dataframe every time I run the function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and cannot find a thread in SO that answers my question. I have an own defined function that counts the number of advisors and customers per product.

Here is the function

```
def countTrigger():
    statistics = pd.DataFrame(
            data = {'Date': [datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")], 
                    'Product': [input()],
                    'Advisor': [len(set(df['Advisor id']))],
                    'Customers': [df.shape[0]]}) 
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(statistics)
    return df
```

`df` is the dataframe which has all the customers and advisors. `df` will be an excel sheet that I import into Python every time there is a new list with a new product.

First I run `countTrigger()` once and write `Product A` into the console, and then run `countTrigger()` a second time with `Product B` into the console.

I want the output to look like this, where there is a new row with new statistics whenever I run `countTrigger()`. Is it also possible to remove `Product A` from the top left corner?:

```
Product A
         Date    Product  Advisors  Customers
0  2019-02-07  Product A        30        175
1  2019-02-07  Product B        40        180
```

In other words, how do I update the dataframe, `statistics`, every time I run the function `countTrigger()`?

Many thanks

Edit: I have now added:

```
global df
df = pd.DataFrame(statistics)
return df
```

However, I cannot get more than two variables into my dataframe. I want the dataframe to grow larger as I use the function.

Comment: Return the df from your function. Append each df result to a list (ie `list_of_dfs.append(countTrigger())`. When complete, use `pd.concat(list_of_dfs)` to concatenate into a single df.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for the reply. How do I do this? I am quite new to Python. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid creating the DataFrame every time inside the function, otherwise, you will overwrite it at any function call. Instead, create the DataFrame first and use the function to simply append new data to it.

```
def update():
    global stat_df
    data = {'Date': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            'Product': input(),
            'Advisor': 'Mr.X',
            'Customers': 1}
    stat_df = stat_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)


##Init the DataFrame
data = {'Date': [],
        'Product': [],
        'Advisor': [],
        'Customers': []}
stat_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)


##Update the DataFrame
update()
print(stat_df)

update()
print(stat_df)

update()
print(stat_df, '\n')
```

The output is:

```
asd
         Date Product Advisor  Customers
0  2019-02-08     asd    Mr.X        1.0 

asda
         Date Product Advisor  Customers
0  2019-02-08     asd    Mr.X        1.0
1  2019-02-08    asda    Mr.X        1.0 

asdasd
         Date Product Advisor  Customers
0  2019-02-08     asd    Mr.X        1.0
1  2019-02-08    asda    Mr.X        1.0
2  2019-02-08  asdasd    Mr.X        1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. however, is it possible to bring `update()` inside another function? Or do I have to run `data` first?

Comment: I have problems saving and storing the file with `df.to_pickle()` and `pd.read_pickle()`. I tried to include `df.to_pickle()` inside the function, but it gets overwritten everytime I run it. What is the best way to avoid the `df` overwritten everytime when it is inside the function `trigger()`?

Comment: This is a new question, you should open a new post for it.